# Styling methods not available on page load, but are after I make an action on the page

Tags: javascript, html, materialize, grafana

I'm trying to write an HTML panel in [Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana).

I have the following code in that panel (a page consists of panels of different types, one such type being HTML):

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <style>
      .input-field.col .dropdown-content [type="checkbox"]+label {
        top: -10px;
      }
      .caret {
        border-color: transparent !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class='input-field col s6'>
          <select class='multiselect' multiple>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Datacenter</option>
            <option value="rs-iad">rs-iad</option>
            <option value="rs-lhr">rs-lhr</option>
            <option value="rs-ord">rs-ord</option>
            <option value="unknown">unknown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $('.multiselect').material_select();
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is stored in a scripted JS panel (example [can be seen here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/public/dashboards/scripted.js)) - When I navigate to this scripted page, I get exceptions at first in the console:

```
TypeError: $(…).material_select is not a function
```

But if I click Edit and go to the HTML content for the panel, modify a single character of the HTML, everything magically renders just fine. How can I get around this? I’m not super great at web development in general, so if I’m doing something completely wrong in my HTML content, apologies.

I’ve tried wrapping the `material_select()` in a `$(document).ready()`, but this produces the same result.

I know this is a bit specific to Grafana, but I can't seem to get any responses from their official forums yet so hoping someone here can help steer me.

Comment: Putting in document ready is a step in the right direction. Also checkt to make sure your link to your library is working correct, because your page is not recognizing material_select as a function, which means it cant find where it is defined. So basically everything that has a script tag is your potential problem.    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.multiselect).material_select();         
     }
</script>

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's what I meant I've tried already

Comment: Is a row with this html panel initially expanded? Grafana won't even try to render anything in panel if the row is collapsed. Scripts are loaded asynchronously so that material_select is not dowloaded from cdn when you call it. You may try to wrap $('.multiselect').material_select() into setTimeout to add some delay. Also you can try to bind .ready() to grafana panel container.